# What is wrong with my proof of $\mathsf{WO}_{\aleph_0}$?

Tags: set-theory

I was wondering whether countable choice for finite sets implied that every infinite set had a countably infinite subset and I came about the following train of thought (which must obviously be incorrect, but I can't exactly state where):

(1) Any infinite set $X$ has a subset $Y$ of size $n$. This is simply guaranteed by a *finite* selection. Simply select $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n$ off $X$ (allowed as it constitutes an in principle finite amount of choices) and you've got your subset $\{x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n\}$ of size $n$.

(2) This means: for every $n$, there exists some function $f_n : n \longrightarrow X$.

(3) Therefore, we can consider the set of all such functions: $\{f_1, f_2, \dots\}$. We can as well consider the set of all such functions' images, i.e., $\{\mathrm{ran}_{f_1}, \mathrm{ran}_{f_2}, \dots\}$.

(4) Consider now $\bigcup \{\mathrm{ran}_{f_1}, \mathrm{ran}_{f_2}, \dots\}$. This clearly constitutes a denumerably infinite subset of $X$.

I was originally trying to work off an argument from countable choice for finite sets for this, but the above argument seems to make use of no other assumption besides the very syntactic rules of our language (and the axioms of $\mathsf{ZF}$, of course), which can't possibly be right...

Perhaps the mistake is that each such function $f_n$ is in principle constructible, but one cannot talk of the set of all such $f_n$ without having already "constructed" each and every one of them, which would require an infinite number of choices be made?

Comment: Why is the union "clearly" denumerably infinite?

Comment: @Trebor Since the $i$th set comes with a bjection with $i$, the union is indeed countable. The issue isn't there, it's in the previous step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's step (3).

In this step you pick, for each $i$, a representative $f_i$ of the set $I_i$ of injective functions from $n$ to $X$. While each $I_i$ is nonempty, you have no way - barring an appeal to choice - to select individual representatives. And you need to pick representatives in order to argue that the union of the codomains is countable; if you take the union of the codomains of all the elements of the $I_i$s, you'll just get $X$ itself.

Comment: Thank you!! Yeah, I totally went over that fact... Thing is, even with countable choice for finite sets I couldn't really choose countably many $f_i$ as the sets $I_i$ will be infinite... Do you know if $\mathsf{WO}_{\aleph_0}$ is provable from countable choice for finite sets? I know the inverse to be true, but I've been struggling with proving the former (if so, please don't "spoil" the answer haha).

Comment: @Sho No, that implication isn't provable. (The ultrafilter lemma, hence AC for finite sets holds in Cohen's original model, but there's an infinite-D-finite set of reals. So not even full AC for finite sets implies $\sf WO_{\aleph_0}$.)

Comment: I see! That is one crazy result... I really need to read a whole lot more on this all... Thank you as always for the thought-out responses @spaceisdarkgreen

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Is there any hope for some sort of relation between $\mathsf{WO}_{\aleph_0}$ and (countable) choice for Dedekind-finite sets?

Comment: @Sho they are equivalent (the countable version, that is… there is an answer on this site but you requested no spoilers above)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Thank you :) (Pretty unrelated question but, is there a particular reason why models of ZF(C) are though to be *transitive*? I was reminiscing of an answer I was once given regarding SL's paradox and that fact stood out to me...)